# Quickest way to evaluate a variable in TCL

Tags: reference, tcl, expect, evaluation

I have a variable *myref* set to:

```
set myref {$expect_out(buffer)}
```

What is the quickest way to get the *$expect_out(buffer)* into *myval*?

```
set myval [HOWTOEVAL $myref]
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you mean by "What is the quickest way to get the $expect_out(buffer) into myval?"

Comment: I have just got the correct answer. Thanks for being involved, coderrick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string containing just the *name* of a variable, you are best off using `set` with only a single argument:

```
set myref {expect_out(buffer)}
puts "The value is [set $myref]"
```

But if you've got that `$` *as well*, the right thing to do is to use `subst` (which means “pretend this was something in double quotes”):

```
set myref {$expect_out(buffer)}
puts "The value is [subst $myref]"
```

Pick the right one for what you've got.

Comment: There couldn't be a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick

```
set myval [subst $$myref]
```

The $myref gets substituted first, and then we substitute that value with the second $

This is an example of the above doing what I think it is you want:

```
set a 12
12
set b a
a
set c [subst $$b]
12
```

Comment: $$ works great in Perl and Makefile, but not in TCL :(

Comment: The code does work, but using `subst` is usually, and with some justification, considered overkill. If one were to use `subst` for this purpose one should use the options to limit the kinds of substitutions the command performs to avoid subtle errors. Your solution is basically the same as and just as correct as the one in the answer patthoyts provided, just with a different formulation. Your formulation looks more elegant but is in fact, perhaps surprisingly, considered less elegant. Still good, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$$` to double de-reference. However you can use the [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/set.htm) command with only a single parameter to read a value from a variable. So:

```
set myval [set $myref]
```

The evaluation of the `set` statement first expands the `$myref` to get the `$expect_out(buffer)` string, this is then the argument to the `set` command itself and is evaluated to return the value of that variable name.

```
% set a(test) hello
hello
% set name "a(test)"
a(test)
% set b [set $name]
hello
```

Comment: Brilliant! However, I suppose this works with myref set to {expect_out(buffer)}, not to {$expect_out(buffer)}! Still, this isn't a major issue for me! Thanks!